# Why is a comparison at the time of evaluation slower than comparing evaluated variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The `slow` method stores the evaluated strings first and then does the comparison on the pre-evaluated strings on return whereas the `fast` method does the comparison at the time of evaluation.

```py
 
import time
from typing import List

def slow(s1:List, s2: List)-> bool:
    w1 = "".join(s1)
    w2 = "".join(s2)
    return w1 == w2

def fast(s1:List, s2: List)-> bool:
    return "".join(s1) == "".join(s2)
 

def main():
    s1 = s2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    fast(s1,s2)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"FAST: Time taken {toc - tic:0.10f} seconds")
    print("")
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    slow(s1,s2)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"SLOW: Time taken {toc - tic:0.10f} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get different results on running this multiple times\

Run 0:

```
FAST: Time taken 0.0000017100 seconds

SLOW: Time taken 0.0000017950 seconds
```

Run1:

```
FAST: Time taken 0.0000018980 seconds

SLOW: Time taken 0.0000014620 seconds
```

Run2 :

```
FAST: Time taken 0.0000021110 seconds

SLOW: Time taken 0.0000016610 seconds
```

Run3

```
FAST: Time taken 0.0000016230 seconds

SLOW: Time taken 0.0000017860 seconds
```

Comment: are you sure? any timing information?

Comment: can you please share how you are measuring the performance ?

Comment: Can you please share your data points of these two functions compared to demo 'fast' vs. 'slower'?

Comment: That's strange, couse for me they're doing absolutely same operations.

Comment: If I may be pedantic; both `fast` and `slow` are *functions*, rather than methods; in the given context.

Comment: @Alpensin Actually they are not. `fast` performs 2 extra `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` instructions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre updated with times

Comment: These run times are virtually the same... (also when timing with `timeit`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to supplement Jean's answer, the following code:

```py
from typing import List
import timeit
import dis

def slow(s1: List, s2: List) -> bool:
    w1 = "".join(s1)
    w2 = "".join(s2)
    return w1 == w2

def fast(s1: List, s2: List) -> bool:
    return "".join(s1) == "".join(s2)

s1 = s2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
           'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

dis.dis("w1 = ''.join(s1); w2 = ''.join(s2); w1 == w2")
print("slow - ", timeit.timeit("slow(s1, s2)", "from __main__ import slow, s1, s2"))
dis.dis("''.join(s1) == ''.join(s2)")
print("fast - ", timeit.timeit("fast(s1, s2)", "from __main__ import fast, s1, s2"))
```

Will produce:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (join)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (s1)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (w1)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
             12 LOAD_METHOD              0 (join)
             14 LOAD_NAME                3 (s2)
             16 CALL_METHOD              1
             18 STORE_NAME               4 (w2)
             20 LOAD_NAME                2 (w1)
             22 LOAD_NAME                4 (w2)
             24 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             26 POP_TOP
             28 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
slow -  0.5605432000000001
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (join)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (s1)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
             10 LOAD_METHOD              0 (join)
             12 LOAD_NAME                2 (s2)
             14 CALL_METHOD              1
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
fast -  0.5361376
```

Which confirms his observations (can be seen through the added `STORE_NAME` and `LOAD_NAME` operations), and that the run times are barely affected by this.

This is probably due to the fact that the `join` and string comparison operation takes up most of the load and the added look-ups doesn't add much time.

Comment: Why does fast take more time in some cases if it doesn't use the `STORE_NAME` and `LOAD_NAME` instructions? Shouldn't it always be faster?

Comment: If you're measuring as in the question, that's not indicative. Timing a single function execution can depend on many factors. Use more idiomatic ways of timing, like the `timeit` module (which runs 1000 runs by default)

Answer (score 2):

without even taking the hassle to disassemble the bytecode, it's apparent that this code creates 2 variables `w1` and `w2` then compares them:

```
w1 = "".join(s1)
w2 = "".join(s2)
return w1 == w2
```

So you have 2 insertions in local variables dictionary and then 2 lookups to perform comparison.

now:

```
return "".join(s1) == "".join(s2)
```

doesn't create any variables. It just compares the result of the `join` call.

the difference is minimal, but name lookup makes a difference specially when the other operations are fast.

Storing references in a variable should be done only when the reference needs to be recalled later. There's nothing wrong with

```
return "".join(s1) == "".join(s2)
```

well, except that if you want to be even faster it would be better to do

```
return s1 == s2
```

as the result of `==` will be the same, without even building a string, even if `s1` and `s2` references are different.

> Now why sometimes the "slow" method *seems* faster and sometimes not ?

That's because the benchmarking isn't accurate enough. The `timeit` module, for instance, runs code several *thousands* of times by default and makes an average. This allows to make up for the potential timing errors on very quick methods.

Comment: I used join as an example. Had it been a more complex function still not storing the evaluated value would make it faster? Also, why does fast give a longer run time in some cases if it uses less instructions?

Comment: I have edited to explain why. But extra instructions added to the same code _has_ to be slower. the measurement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces different result each time because your test-set is not big-enough. Because your CPU constantly switches between task they sometimes take significantly longer. This is a result of pure chance.

To make your results statistically significant you need to use a bigger dataset. I used this:

> ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] * 10000000

```
#Run1
FAST: Time taken 3.0921943630 seconds
SLOW: Time taken 3.1013537180 seconds

#Run2
FAST: Time taken 3.1208893380 seconds
SLOW: Time taken 3.1256201450 seconds

#Run3
FAST: Time taken 3.2086985350 seconds
SLOW: Time taken 3.1169058040 seconds
```

We see that both operations run  in virtually the same time.

Comment: Shouldn't fast always be running in less time since slow has to store the values? Is it just by chance?

Comment: Its just by chance.